# Too Many Requests for Amazon Managed Blockchain service

Tags: amazon-web-services, blockchain, amazon-managed-blockchain

How many requests can be accepted by Amazon Managed Blockchain service? Facing Too Many Requests error while creating channel. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Can you share the logs where you are facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on number of channels you can create in AmazonManagedBlockchain and in Hyperledger Fabric there is no concept of deleting a channel.

If you really need all those channels and have to create new then you can reach out to AWS team with your use case for limit increase.